# Ubuntu installation on Windows , I can't find my way back.

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, usb-creator

So recently I have installed Ubuntu as an OS in addition to my Windows because it looked good and I have used it in the past and I liked it. Before I installed Ubuntu, they (the website) have given me a help list that shows that I **will** have the option of having Windows aside to Ubuntu (dual install), while I work with the Ubuntu OS. They told me that if I either put it in a CD or USB drive, I'll be okay.

So there I was, installing Ubuntu, saving the Ubuntu file on my USB drive first, then afterwards clicking it and therefore proceeded to install.

The problem is once I installed Ubuntu, it directed me to the 'login' page **without** giving me an option for dual-installing (you know, the language portion and so on). Now I tried both to suspend and shut off, and it seems like I cannot access my Windows files/account anymore and it really is unfortunate.

Now I am FREAKING out, because this is a shared computer that my family uses (it's like a main computer in the house) and **everyone's** files are on this. It is extremely crucial for me to get these Windows files back because if I don't, my life will end tonight.

Please, if someone can help me, I will love you forever. Please just help me, this is **urgent**.

I'm sure a lot of people have experienced this too, but I have found nothing on the website helpful for me as Ubuntu is a very new thing for me.

Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: Generally, family computers are bad candidates for experiments. Anyway, not all may be lost, can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` from Ubuntu. If Windows paritions are still intact, you might even still be able to dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is not to panic :)

First when turning on your computer hold down the shift key that way if grub is installed it will come out of hiding

If that failed try mikewhatever suggestions and post output

If Windows exists, i presume you still have the ubuntu installation disk, if so, try option 2 found here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and use the recommended repair option.

Answer (score 0):

If Linux has not installed then what you do is just press F8 continously on pressing the power button.

If linux is not installed then windows will open in a safe mode then you can save all the data that is required to you in a pen drive and then after you can format in any how.

Hope i have helped you...

Its just a suggestion my friend and it wont affect your computer if you do this.

Hoping for the result.

thanks